# How to access CocoaPod framework from an embedded project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using CocoaPods to install and manage a set of libraries. They install fine and I can import them without any issue in my main project called 'Main'. However, within that project I have another project called 'Second'. I am unable to import a framework in any of the swift files within that project that are accessible to the main project. I have tried installing the pods to the second project but it turns into a huge mess and I would prefer not to have duplicates as I make changes to the libraries themselves.

If anyone has any suggestions on the best way of achieving this it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try to set(Select the checkbox) the "Target" of the library for "Second" project also from the "File Inspector" so that the framework which you had already added can also be added to another project.
And in your "pod" try to remove any code related to "target" and just add the pod list alone